# Writing log to Windows Event Viewer

Tags: c#, windows, event-log, event-viewer, eventsource

Is it possible for a windows service/web application (c#) to write log entries where its running under a windows domain account that is NOT a local admin?

I have tried both of the following for a NON admin windows domain account:

1. Writing to the Application log (with a 'Test' source). but this gave me **'Access Denied'** error.
2. Initially setup a new custom log called 'Test' that would have appeared under 'Applications and Service Logs' using a local admin windows user account.
   I then tried to write logs to this using a non admin windows user account but still ended up getting '**Access denied**' error.

I have seen suggestions where the registry needs to be modified but i really don't want to go down that route as it feels hacky and..well..just not right!

I can get both options above to work when i switch the windows user to a local admin, but i don't want this.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated..
(Apologies in advance if this is duplicate POST)

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant access to the log. See [Delegating access to the event logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-vista/cc722385(v=ws.10)#delegating-access-to-the-event-logs)

> Open Registry Editor.
>
> Navigate to the following registry path:
>
> `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog`
>
> You will see that there are keys available for each event log. Select the event log for which you want to delegate access.
>
> Add a new key with the name CustomSD to the event log you selected.
>
> Add a new String value to the CustomSD key. The name of this string is not required, but it represents the access control list for the event log in the Security Descriptor Definition Language (SDDL) syntax. In this procedure this value will be referred to as SDDLACL.

As for the SDDL, see [Security Descriptor String Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/secauthz/security-descriptor-string-format)